# Perplexing section of Moreh Nevuchim

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, rambam, moreh-nevuchim

The Rambam writes in [Moreh Nevuchim: Prefatory Remarks/Directions for the Study of this Work](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Introduction%2C_Prefatory_Remarks.27) (numbering mine):

> (1) ואני משביע באלהי יתברך כל מי שיקרא מאמרי זה שלא יפרש ממנו אפילו
> דבר אחד, ולא יבאר ממנו לזולתו, אלא מה שהוא מבואר מפורש בדברי מי שקדמני
> מחכמי תורתנו הידועים. אמנם מה שיבין ממנו ממה שלא אמרו זולתי מחכמינו לא
> יבארהו לזולתו, ולא יהרוס ויקפוץ (עצמו) להשיב על דברי,(2) שאיפשר שיהיה
> מה שהבינו מדברי חילוף מה שרציתיו, ויזיקני גמול תחת רצותי להועילו,
> ויהיה משלם רעה תחת טובה. אבל יתבונן בו כל מי שיבא לידו, ואם ירפא לו
> מדווה לבבו ואפילו בעניין אחד מכל מה שיסופק, יודה השם ויספיק לו מה
> שהבין. ואם לא ימצא בו דבר שיועילהו בשום צד יחשבהו כאלו לא חובר,(3) ואם
> יראה לו בו שום הפסד כפי מחשבתו, יפרשהו וידין אותו לכף זכות, **ואפילו
> בפירוש רחוק**. כמו שחוייב עלינו בחוק המונינו, כל שכן בחוק ידועינו
> וחכמי תורתנו המשתדלים להועילנו באמת כפי השגתם
>
> (1) I adjure any reader of my book, in the name of the Most High, not
> to add any explanation even to a single word: nor to explain to
> another any portion of it except such passages as have been fully
> treated of by previous theological authorities: he must not teach
> others anything that he has learnt from my work alone, and that has
> not been hitherto discussed by any of our authorities. (2) The reader
> must, moreover, beware of raising objections to any of my statements,
> because it is very probable that he may understand my words to mean
> the exact opposite to what I intended to say. He will injure me, while
> I endeavoured to benefit him. “He will requite me evil for good.” Let
> the reader make a careful study of this work; and if his doubt be
> removed on even one point, let him praise his Maker and rest contented
> with the knowledge he has acquired. But if he derive from it no
> benefit whatever, he may consider the book as if it had never been
> written. (3) Should he notice any opinions with which he does not
> agree, let him endeavour to find a suitable explanation, even if it
> seem far-fetched, in order that he may judge me charitably. Such a
> duty we owe to every one. We owe it especially to our scholars and
> theologians, who endeavour to teach us what is the truth according to
> the best of their ability.

- Starting with (1), why does the Rambam command us in Hashem's name to
  not teach anything in Moreh Nevuchim that is his original teaching?
  Why do we do so? Further on this secretive theme, he implores us in (2) to forget anything we don't understand.
- (2) Why are we best off not asking kashes? Why is the reason given we
  might have him backwards? Especially right after dedicating a lot of ink further up to explaining how nothing doubtful is unexplained and no words are wasted, how can we end up still getting him 100% wrong?
- (3) If we are commanded in Hashem's name to not to add any *explanation* to what he writes, and he implores us to avoid asking kashas (see the rest of this section for additional emphasis on this), why does
  he say here that if we have a kasha, we should do our best to imagine
  even a far-fetched *explanation* on how to understand him and judge him favourably?

I can think of a few possible answers, especially to the last 2, but I would like to know if there are any commentaries or commentators who explain these questions?

I am most interested in the first bullet point, and I am especially keen to get a variety of answers that perhaps disagree so I can compare.

Comment: This might give you further insight (one of my favourite Jewish pieces) https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14113&st=&pgnum=85&hilite=
The Mabit (contemporary of SA) explains how the paradox of not asking questions and yes asking questions co-exist. 
This is also explained by Rebbe Nachman https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.64.1.1?vhe=Likutei_Moharan_-_rabenubook.com&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he
This piece 64 is explaining a lot about how to understand questions. Podcast Inward also explains this piece by Rebbe Nachman. @rabbiKaii, I always love your thoughtful questions!

Comment: thank you @fulltimekollelguy! Do any of these address the MN specifically? I am extra keen to understand the first bullet point

Comment: Good questions and I won't try answers. I _will_ mention that this reminds me of what my rebbi a"h told me about learning agadata: "You have to let it speak to you." It's hard stuff, you aren't going to understand it that well, maybe, you can get glimpses of wonderful ideas. If you have a kashya, even if you're right, it might be the part that is the covering rather than the essence. Trust that there is a deep essence even if you can't see it (yet). See the MN's explanation of "the flash of the turning sword".

Comment: A related question - why is there a need for hiding the essence (or any kind of obfuscation)? Why couldn’t agadata or MN be fully explicated, with every detail and intended meaning spelled out clearly?

Comment: @user9806 that would make a great, separate question, if you decide to ask it. There is a lot to say.